# Sorting Array with HTML entities

Tags: php, html, arrays

I am trying to do an array sort with special characters using PHP.

I retrieve strings from database and they are being displayed properly on the web browser. But when i check the source of the page i see their html entities.

Display as İnan

On source it is `&#304;nan`

So when I do an array sort, it is not sorted properly, I guess because of the html entities.

I tried to decode before putting them into the array but no luck.

I also tried this:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL,'TURKISH');
asort($stu_list,SORT_LOCALE_STRING);
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use html_entity_decode to find the actual characters of the HTML entity and use a custom sort.

```
function CustomSort($a, $b)
{
    $da = html_entity_decode($a);
    $db = html_entity_decode($b);

    if ($da == $db) return 0;

    return $da > $db ? 1 : -1;
}

uasort($stu_list, "CustomSort");
```

Comment: it sorts the same way as the normal sort function does. It puts this letter "İ" at the beginning whereas it should be after "ı".

Comment: for İ it is &#304; for ı it is &#305;

Comment: Which is why it sorts İ before ı

Comment: It also puts "İ" before "A" probably because of & has priority over A. So any suggestions?